# Connection between inner products over prime fields and finite non-prime fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, finite-fields, inner-products

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for all the helpers.

I'm trying to develop an intuition for finite fields and I've stumbled upon the following question (it's not a homework question) which I cannot answer myself (my abstract algebra is *very* rusty).

Let $q=p^h$ for some prime number $p$ and let $x,y\in\mathbb{F}_q^n$. It is known that $x$ and $y$ can be viewed as $x',y'\in\mathbb{F}_p^{hn}$.
Is it true that $\langle x',y' \rangle =0 $ if and only if $\mathrm{tr}(\langle x,y \rangle)=0$?

By $\langle x, y\rangle$ I mean $\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i$ (and similarly $\langle x',y'\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{hn}x'_iy'_i$).

Comment: If $p\equiv 3\bmod 4,h=2,n=1$ then no, there is no $\Bbb{F}_p$-basis of $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ giving what you want.

Comment: Thank you! how can I mark that comment as an answer?

Comment: Comments aren't answers. Can you prove my claim? You can take $p^h = 9$ if the general case isn't clear to you. With a proof you can write your own answer.